# robots.txt, Angular, S3 bucket and Google Console

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, robots.txt, google-developers-console

I have a website built with Angular hosted on an AWS S3 bucket. I want to index it on Google, but it can't find the robots.txt file. I have placed it in src/robots.txt along with the sitemap.xml, but Google doesn't seem to locate it. Is there any solution?

[google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bapfz.png)

[robots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcYci.png)

[root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5TZO.png)

Thank you!

I have tried acces directly mydomain/sitemap.xml and it workd but mydomain/robots.txt doesnt work.